# Connectedness of $Y \cup A$ and $Y \cup B$

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Let $Y$ be a nonempty closed subset of $X \subset \Bbb R^n$. Assume $X\setminus Y = A\cup B$, with $A,B \subset X$ nonempty, open and disjoint. Prove $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are connected.
If $B$ is not open, show with a counterexample that $Y\cup B$ could be not connected.

I understand that $X\setminus Y$ is not connected, precisely, $(A, B)$ is a separation for $X\setminus Y$. I am trying to prove this by contradiction. I suppose $Y\cup A$ not connected, so, exists nonempty $C, D$ open in $Y\cup A$ and disjoint such that $Y\cup A = C\cup D$.

Also, $X=(Y\cup A)\cup B =(C\cup D)\cup B$, but I am stuck in this point. I tried to understand with some sketches but I have no idea how to use the fact $Y$ is closed.

I would really appreciate any help to take it from here.

Comment: FALSE. E.g. $n=1$ and $X=\Bbb R$ and $Y=\Bbb Z$ and $A=\cup_{n\in\Bbb Z}(2n,2n+1)$ and $B=\cup_{n\in\Bbb Z}(2n-1,2n).$ Did you omit some additional conditions?

Comment: I am completely sure I did not omit some additional conditions. The professor proposed this exercise as I wrote it. Thanks for your counterexample. I am trying to understand why $Y\cup A$ is not connected. I was thinking the same $Y$ and $A$ as the separation, but $Y$ is closed. So, could you help me to identify the two open sets for the separation.

Comment: In my example let $C=(-1/2, 3/2)$ and $D=\Bbb R \setminus \overline C.$